# List all pending changelists in a sandbox

Tags: version-control, perforce, sandbox

I have a perforce sandbox, and I have created a new changeset in the sandbox, which is still pending, i.e. I have not submitted it yet. How do I obtain the changeset number. `p4 changelists` gives me changelists for all sandboxes, I only need for mine, and that only the pending one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
p4 changes -c CLIENT -s pending
```

where CLIENT is the name of your client spec ("sandbox").

From "p4 help changes":

```
changes -- Display list of pending and submitted changelists
changelists -- synonym for 'changes'

p4 changes [-i -t -l -L -f] [-c client] [ -e changelist# ]
        [-m max] [-s status] [-u user] [file[revRange] ...]

    ...

    The -c client flag displays only submitted by the specified client.

    ...

    The -s status flag limits the output to changelists with the specified
    status. Specify '-s pending', '-s shelved', or '-s submitted'.
```

Comment: Shorter to type, but not as perfect an answer: `p4 opened`. Any files opened in a numbered changelist will show that changelist number in their output.